# How can we speed-up flash builder debug launch.. other than heapsize change?

Tags: flash-builder, flexbuilder, launch

Is there any configuration or method by which we can speedup debug or  launch of application..  i have machine with 4 GB RAM, core i-7 processor. still it launches application from flash builder in 4 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uncheck all the validators.. it will speed up the build process :)

Answer (score 0):

I have another optimization.

Probably you don't depend on the design mode.
So here is a simple trick which you can use to speed up the Flash Builder.

Open the default sdk folder which you are using.
(By default it's located /Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.5/sdks/{the default sdk 4.5.0} for Mac OS similar for windows (C:\Program Files\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\sdks{the default sdk 4.5.0})

Then edit the file with name flex-sdk-description.xml

Just change the value of the version tag to something like this 4.10.0 :)
Save the file and restart the Flash Builder.

After this change the builder will not use the design view.
"Design View not Supported - incompatible SDK version"

If you want to use it again just put the correct value i.e. 4.5.0 (Should be the same as the name of the folder in which is located the file).

Best,
Emil

Answer (score 0):

Here are more things that you can do to improve your (IDE) Eclipse/ Flex Builder

http://www.redcodelabs.com/2012/03/eclipse-speed-up-flashbuilder/

- Modify eclipse.ini
- Create a ram disk(virtual disk) on memory,..
- Disable unneeded validators

etc...